# Inner join and Sub query with three different relations

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

**Background**: Pokemon welcomed its 20th Anniversary in 2016. 
As the Pokemon Pikachu is the most iconic Pokemon, Moke club is planning to give out a one time award for the member that has caught the most number of Pikachu by sending an e-voucher through email.

**Question:** Find out the member who has caught the *most number* of Pikachu in the year 2016. Display the member name, member ID, number of Pikachu caught, and email address. Using subquery or subquery with inner join.

Relations involved: Participation, PokemomParticipation and Member (Below is a snapshot of the relation table. (Table has been modified to display result that is relevant to the query)

PokemomParticipation: 
[PokemonParticipation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AetZG.png)

Pokemom: 
[Pokemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOTlm.png)

Member: 
[Member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUP8G.png)

From the database, we can see that the member who has caught the most number of Pikachu has a memberID of 10 and its name is Marcus. The pokemon ID of Pikachu is 10. Hence, these three relations are needed to solve the questions.

My answer(Wrong Solution):

```
USE MokeClub 

GO

SELECT m.MemberID, m.Name, m.Email,pp.NumCaught

FROM Member m INNER JOIN PokemonParticipation pp

ON m.MemberID = pp.MemberID

INNER JOIN Pokemon pk 

ON pp.PokemonID =pk.PokemonID

WHERE pp.DateCaught >'2015-Dec-31' AND pp.DateCaught <'2017-Jan-01' AND pk.PokemonName ='Pikachu' 

AND 
NumCaught = (SELECT MAX(NumCaught) 

FROM PokemonParticipation      )
```

Picture: [WRONG Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwETC.png)
The problem with this solution is that nothing is displayed.

Many thanks to your generous help!
I have tried to research on the web, but unable to get out some meaning from the explanation. I am still a beginner to SQL query.

**EDITED(CORRECT SOLUTIONS)**
[Correct Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN9Ig.png)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: So what is the question? Wrong result? Any error? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry about that, just realised I did not specify the question. This is not a homework, I have created a database and try to play around with it by raising possible queries using the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interested specifically for the row where `NumCaught` has a maximum value
 
for `PokemonName ='Pikachu'` and not for the maximum value of `NumCaught` in general.  
So change the last condition to this:

```
AND 
pp.NumCaught = (
  SELECT MAX(t.NumCaught) FROM PokemonParticipation t
  WHERE t.PokemonID = pk.PokemonID
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2andSDiADaNz5oaZ6u94A9/0)

Comment: Thank you for your response, really appreciate it. However, as I try to swap, it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean swap?

Comment: Check the link in my answer.

Comment: Woah, Thank you very much. I think is my SQL software couldn't recognise the code. Really thank you very much for the help! Have a nice evening!

Comment: If this solved the problem consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your joins are correct, you're not getting a result because the `SELECT MAX(NumCaught) FROM PokemonParticipation` returns `13` from other Pokemons. You need to add another condition to filter for Pikachu or you simply switch to TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
   m.MemberID, m.Name, m.Email,pp.NumCaught

FROM Member m INNER JOIN PokemonParticipation pp

ON m.MemberID = pp.MemberID

INNER JOIN Pokemon pk 

ON pp.PokemonID =pk.PokemonID

WHERE pp.DateCaught >'2015-Dec-31'  -- i would prefer >= '2016-Jan-01' (just in case there's a time portion)
  AND pp.DateCaught <'2017-Jan-01'
  AND pk.PokemonName ='Pikachu' 

ORDER BY pp.NumCaught DESC
```

I'm using `WITH TIES` if there are multiple users with the same high number

Comment: Thank you for your kind responses. I have managed to find the solution after numerous tries. If you would like to take a look, it is above.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but TOP is way more efficient :-)

Comment: Yes, the code is much cleaner. Thank you for your advise, have a nice evening:)